# How do I make form_for to complete with the previously submitted data when validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, submit, form-for

- Given that I have a large form
- When the user submits it
- And the validation of the data fails
- Then the user is redirected to the previous page again
- And the form should contain the data that the user previously submitted

---

How can I achieve the last part? :P
There is something like `flash[]` for the form_for helper?
I have to use AJAX?

Comment: This is the default behavior for form_for, please provide a sample of your form code.

Comment: Don't redirect back to the previous page, but use render. If you want a detailed answer, show your (controller) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments have suggested, this *can* be the default behavior, if you're using best practices.

Here's an example of the new/create controller actions that should exhibit said behavior:

```
def new
  @model = MyModel.new
end

def create
  @model = MyModel.new(params[:my_model])

  if @model.save
    redirect_to my_models_url, :notice => "Success!"
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "There was an error"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: I was redirecting to the previous page and the data was being erased, of course, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your view if request.method == :post, and if it is then use the data in params[] instead. It will contain the data you just posted.